# Prolog: getting first float from list

Tags: prolog

I'm having trouble getting the first float element in a list. What I've done so far (completely useless, maybe):

```
get_float( _, F ) :- float( F ).

get_float( [ First | Rest ], F ) :-
    get_float( Rest, F ).
```

Gives me this:

```
some_pred( P ) :-
    get_float( SomeList, FloatNumber ),
    writeln( FloatNumber ). % --> prints a stack position
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
get_float([], _).

get_float( [ First | Rest ], F ) :-
    (float(First), F = First);
    get_float( Rest, F ).
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your first case doesn't examine the list at all. Try this:

```
get_float([F|_], F) :- float(F).
```

Otherwise you're on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

The logic should be:

1. If the first item is a float, that's your guy.
2. If the first item ISN'T a float, get the first float from the rest of the list.

It looks like you are trying to do #2 in your second predicate.  Your first predicate looks to be trying to do #1, but isn't testing to see that F is the first element of the list.